# How to get a live streaming from a website ( python )

Tags: javascript, python, html, blob, http-live-streaming

i'm trying to crawl a website and get a live streaming video from it so i can make some video processing on it then display it in a python program : 
the link to the video live streaming is : https://www.france.tv/france-2/direct.html

In the code source of the page i see that there is a video html tag which src attribute is a url for a blob file.

In the network debug tool of chrome I see that i'm getting ferquently mpd files , I tried to open one of them using VLC but not working.